# Using boost::shared_ptr to refer to iterator without copying data?

Tags: c++, boost

Inside a loop I need to call a function which has an argument of type `pcl::PointIndicesPtr`. This is actually a `boost::shared_ptr< ::pcl::PointIndices>`. Is there a way to do this without having to copy the underlying data? I only could it get to work by using `make_shared`, which copies the object if I understand it correctly.

```
for (std::vector<pcl::PointIndices>::const_iterator it = cluster_indices.begin (); it !=     cluster_indices.end (); ++it)
{          
   pcl::PointIndicesPtr indices_ptr2 =boost::make_shared<pcl::PointIndices>(*it);          
}
```

For example this will crash at runtime:

```
for (std::vector<pcl::PointIndices>::const_iterator it = cluster_indices.begin (); it !=     cluster_indices.end (); ++it)
{          
   pcl::PointIndices test  = *it;    
   pcl::PointIndicesPtr indices_ptr3(&test);        
}
```

Comment: Of course it will, you're passing a pointer to a temporary, which is destroyed the moment the loop iterates or ends...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the implementation of the function you are calling and what else your code does with the object. There is no "one right answer".

For example, if the function can't possibly access the object after it returns, the right answer might be to wrap the existing object with a `shared_ptr` with a dummy destructor. But if the function stashes the `shared_ptr`, that won't work.

If your own code never modifies the object, constructing the object with `make_shared` in the first place may be the right answer. But if your code modifies the object while the function expects it not to change later, that won't work.

You have to make a decision based on all the information.

The most important question to answer -- **why** does the function you are calling take a `shared_ptr`? Does it have a good reason? If so, what is that reason? If not, why not change it to take a reference?

Comment: +1 for  "The most important question to answer -- why does the function you are calling take a shared_ptr"

Comment: I can't modify the function I want to call, since it's third-party code. But I don't think it will access the objects after it returned.

Comment: I was just concerned that the object is copied unnecessarily, but it works reasonably fast, so I think I'll stick to using make_shared

Answer (score 0):

Could you use BOOST_FOREACH?
i.e.

```
BOOST_FOREACH(pcl::PointIndiciesPtr ptr; cluster_indicies)
{
    //do something with shared_ptr
}
```

Comment: This seems pretty unrelated. And a syntax error as well